# Ubuntu Launcher not displayed in VMware

Tags: launcher, vmware

I have installed VMware Player in my laptop with Windows 7 as the host OS and Ubuntu 12.04 as guest OS. Everything went fine, but my menu pane which appears vertically on the left side of the desktop of Ubuntu 12.04 is not getting displayed. I did the same installation with VirtualBox, and it's running good. Should I install any additional features so that the menu gets enabled in the virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- First try to enable hardware acceleration for video on VMware Player if not already enabled.
- You can also try installing [VMware Tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools) inside Ubuntu.

This happens because, VMware Player Guest OS can't directly access the video capability outside on Host OS. So Ubuntu checked for video capability and switched to 2D interface.

Comment: Well I've installed that too previously. Still having the problem.

Comment: If you really need it, you can use VirtualBox... Vmware doesn't seem to support Unity 3D interfaces...